# How do I find all possible combinations of the form ±1 ± 2 ± 3 ± ... ± n = k with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I am having a very difficult time to come up with a simple solution using LINQ in C# for this problem:

For two given numbers n and k, find all possible combinations of the form ±1 ± 2 ± 3 ± ... ± n = k.

For example, for n = 5 and k = 3, the result would be
`"-1+2+3+4-5 = 3", "-1+2+3+4-5 = 3"`

```
public static void Main()
{
    int firstNNumbers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int numberOfOperations = firstNNumbers - 1;
    int targetSum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    char[] set = { '+', '-' };
    bool hasSolution = false;
    GetAllOperatorCombinations(set, numberOfOperations, targetSum, ref hasSolution);
    if (hasSolution)
    {
        return;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("N/A");
}
public static int CheckIfGoodAndPrint(string prefix, int targetSum, ref bool hasSolution)
{
    const int Number = 2;
    int thisSum = 1;
    if (prefix == null)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < prefix.Length; i++)
    {
        if (prefix[i] == '-')
        {
            thisSum -= i + Number;
        }
        else
        {
            thisSum += i + Number;
        }
    }
    if (thisSum != targetSum)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    PrinEquation(prefix, targetSum);
    hasSolution = true;
    return 1;
}
static void GetAllOperatorCombinations(char[] set, int k, int targetSum, ref bool hasSolution)
{
    int n = set.Length;
    GetAllOperatorCombinations(set, "", n, k, targetSum, ref hasSolution);
}
static void GetAllOperatorCombinations(char[] set, string prefix, int n, int k, int targetSum, ref bool hasSolution)
{
    if (k == 0)
    {
        int test = CheckIfGoodAndPrint(prefix, targetSum, ref hasSolution);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        string newPrefix = prefix + set[i];
        GetAllOperatorCombinations(set, newPrefix, n, k - 1, targetSum, ref hasSolution);
    }
}
private static void PrinEquation(string prefix, int targetSum)
{
    string equation = "";
    for (int i = 1; i <= prefix.Length; i++)
    {
        equation += i + " " + prefix[i - 1] + " ";
        if (i == prefix.Length)
        {
            equation += (i + 1) + " = " + targetSum;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(equation);
}
```

This is the code that works for all cases but I know it can be done a lot shorter with linq.

Comment: No.  You need a recursive algorithm which is not what linq does.

Comment: @jdweng you can do recursive using `linq`...

Comment: Isn't this basically the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ - so you believe there is a solution to this problem with LINQ only? now I am curious, pls show me

Comment: Well I am stuck on this for 2 days and my teacher won't let me advance the course I am taking if I can't figure out how to get it done with linq. This is basically the last step to get a big project as assignment.

Comment: I'm unsure what the exact requirement is regarding LINQ. Does the entire task need to be solved using a single query? Or does it just need to make use of some LINQ utilities?

Comment: @jdweng No, you don't need a recursive algorithm for this.  You basically just need to iterate over the 2^n different combinations of +/- signs applied to the equation and figure out which ones work, which can definitely be done in an iterative fashion.

Comment: @ juharr : You are taking n of x which requires recursive algorithm. So if you have number -10 to 10  you can get three from A) 1 + 2  B) 4 - 1 C) 5 - 2 D) 6 - 2 - 1 E) 7 - 3 - 1 F) 8 - 5 G) 8 - 4 - 1 H) 8 - 3 - 2 I) 9 - 6 J) 9 - 5 - 1 K) 9 - 4 - 2 L) 10 - 7 M) 10 - 6 - 1 N) 10 - 5 - 2 O) 10 - 4 - 3

Comment: @jdweng while a recursive solution might be conceptually simplest, this problem most certainly does not _require_ a recursive algorithm, as the algorithm that juharr describes is iterative and works perfectly well (not to mention it's what came to mind immediately when I saw this question, so it's not exactly an uncommon approach.) I think you may have misinterpreted the problem, as you seem to suggest a solution to a more complicated problem (in OP's case, I believe each number from 0 to N _must_ appear in the sequence, just with an optional - sign; the numbers themselves are _not_ optional)

Comment: It is possible to write a more efficient algorithm using recursion where you break out as soon as the sum goes to high or too low for the sum of the rest of the numbers to get to k.  So for the n=5, k=3 example if you do +5+4+3 at that point you know you cannot get to k even if you subtract all the rest of the numbers and so you can no bother with any solutions below that.

Comment: @Moira  : juharr code only returns solutions with 5 items.

Comment: @jdweng which is fine according to the provided problem statement. You're completely right, but you're trying to solve a harder problem here.

Comment: FYI: n=5, k=3 has 3 solutions "-1-2-3+4+5", "+1-2+3-4+5", "-1+2+3+4-5"

Comment: @jdweng Even if the problem were to take a subset of the numbers -n to n and sum them to get k, that's still a finite number of combinations that can be iterated over.  In this case it's a matter of including or excluding 2n different numbers which comes out to 2^(2n) combinations.  So like Moira said, a harder problem.

Comment: No.  If you have number 1,2,3, 4 juharr will get {1}, {2},{3}, {4}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {1,4},{2,3},{2,4}, {3,4}, {1,2,3}, {1,2,4}, {2,3,4}, {1,2,3,4}.  But not {1,3,4}.

Comment: @jdweng What are you even talking about?  if you want all the sets of the numbers 1-4, there will be 16  (2^n) of them and you're missing the empty set {}.  If you want to exclude the empty set then yeah it's (2^n) - 1, but if you want the all the sets of 1-4 positive and negative then there are 2^(2n) = 256 (including empty)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a possible iterative solution:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        const int N = 5, K = 3;

        // 1 represents +, 0 represents -
        var results = Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << N)
            .Select(bits =>
            {
                var permutation = Enumerable.Range(0, N)
                    .Select(n => (bits & (1 << n)) != 0 ? (n + 1) : -(n + 1))
                    .ToList();

                var sum = permutation.Sum();
                var str = string.Join(" + ", permutation);

                return new {sum, str};
            })
            .Where(intermediate => intermediate.sum == K)
            .Select(intermediate => $"{intermediate.str} = {K}");

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", results));
    }
}
```

This makes use of the fact that one can iterate through the binary representation of all integers from 0 to 2^N - 1, in order to generate all possible permutations of either `+` or `-` (in this case, represented by bits 1 and 0 respectively.)

This essentially turns this problem into a single loop.

---

Why this works is pretty intuitive; to put it very simply, there are 2^N possible N-length sequences of a two-valued type, and there are also 2^N integers between 0 and 2^N - 1 (obviously), so each possibility must be encountered exactly once.

---

For your inputs N = 5 and K = 3, this produces ([ideone](https://ideone.com/Z7NvZI))

```
-1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + -5 = 3
1 + -2 + 3 + -4 + 5 = 3
-1 + -2 + -3 + 4 + 5 = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static IEnumerable<string> CombinationOfSigns(this int n,int k)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> signs = new string[] {""};
            return Enumerable.Range(0, n)
                .Aggregate(signs,(e,y) => e
                .SelectMany(x => new string[] { x + "-", x + "+" }))
                .Where(combination => Enumerable.Range(0, n)
                .Aggregate(0, (sum, number)=> combination[number] == '+' ? sum + (number + 1) : sum - (number + 1)) == k);
        }
```

This what I came up with in the end.